# Extracting values based on multiple criteria in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have an online schedule in Google Sheets. The columns are given dates of a month (1,2,3...etc) and the rows represent specific people.

The schedule consists of working specific shifts, administrating sick leaves and vacations. More than one of these parameters (SZ or B are important for me in this case) can appear in a row. The table looks similar to this setup:

```
        1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10   11   12   13   etc
name1   SZ  N   E       X   B   B.      N   E    B    SZ   NE
name2   N   N       X   SZ  SZ  SZ      N   N    N    N    E
name3   N   E       N   E       N   E       N    E         N
name4   NE      SZ  SZ  B   B   SZ  SZ  B  B
```

I would like to get back the dates when SZ or B appeared for each name.
For example: for *name1*: 1,12 and *name2*: 5,6,7 and *name4*: 3,4,7,8.
The same goes for Bs. And of course there is the NULL to think of.

Is there a way to combine IFERROR and INDEX-MATCH functions to be able to extract data this way?

Comment: Can you share a copy of your spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for SZ,

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(", ", true, if(B2:N2="SZ", B$1:N$1, "")))
```

I imagine the adjustment for B is self-evident.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! For my needs I have reshaped the formula a little bit:
`=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(", "; TRUE; IF(INDEX(OtherSheet!$C$175:$AG$233;MATCH(B7;OtherSheet!$A$175:$A$233;0))="SZ"; OtherSheet!$C$173:$AG$173; "")))`